# Transform every element of a list with map function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a Haskell beginner and currently doing a basic workshop. This is my question:

Given the code:

```hs
data Car = Car {brand :: String, year :: Int} deriving (Show)

brands = take 100 (cycle ["Renault", "Mercedes", "Volvo", "Banana", "Robin Hood"])

years = [1950..2050]

maybeCars = map (\ tuple -> 
    if (fst tuple == "Banana") then
        Nothing
    else
        Just Car {brand = fst tuple, year = snd tuple}
    ) (zip brands years)
```

the following list of Car Objects gets created:

```
maybeCars = [Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1950}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1951}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1952}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1954}),Just (Car {brand
= "Renault", year = 1955}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1956}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1957}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1959}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year
= 1960}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1961}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1962}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1964}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1965}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1966}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1967}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1969}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1970}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1971}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1972}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1974}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1975}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1976}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1977}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1979}),Just
(Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1980}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1981}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1982}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1984}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1985}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1986}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1987}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1989}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1990}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1991}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1992}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1994}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 1995}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 1996}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 1997}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 1999}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2000}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2001}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2002}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year =
2004}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2005}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2006}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2007}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2009}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2010}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2011}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2012}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2014}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2015}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2016}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2017}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2019}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2020}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2021}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2022}),Nothing,Just (Car
{brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2024}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2025}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2026}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2027}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2029}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2030}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2031}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2032}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2034}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year = 2035}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2036}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2037}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2039}),Just (Car {brand
= "Renault", year = 2040}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2041}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2042}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2044}),Just (Car {brand = "Renault", year
= 2045}),Just (Car {brand = "Mercedes", year = 2046}),Just (Car {brand = "Volvo", year = 2047}),Nothing,Just (Car {brand = "Robin Hood", year = 2049})]
```

I have to solve the following task: 
Try to transform make every car in maybeCars a 'Volvo' 
with the map function.

I tried to use a helper function of type "Maybe Car -> Maybe Car" and passed it to the map, but i failed to update the string and ran in a lot of different mistakes. What would be a possible solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to check if it is a `Just …`, and in that case thus convert the brand of the car:

```
toVolvo :: Maybe Car -> Maybe Car
toVolvo (Just c) = Just c{brand="Volvo"}
toVolvo Nothing = Nothing
```

Or you can make use of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to perform a mapping on the item the `Just` wraps. So for `Maybe`, `fmap` has type `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`. You thus can implement `toVolvo` as:

```
toVolvo :: Functor f => f Car -> f Car
toVolvo = fmap (\c -> c {brand="Volvo"})
```

You can then use `toVolvo` for example as function for `map` to perform a mapping over a list.